# Removing duplicates in a list and using the duplicate to create a sublist in the first occuring list index

Tags: python

I haves been looking for an answer to this but can't seem to find anything that does this elegantly or pythonic.

Basically if I have a list:

A = [["1a", "ab"], ["2b", "cd"], ["1a", "ef"]]

I want to identify every item which has the same value in their first index and if that's the case amend the list so that A becomes:

A = [["1a", ["ab", "ef"]], ["2b", "cd"]]

As ordering is important I am trying to avoid dictionaries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/1400768

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionaries: How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: Why not `["2b", ["cd"]]`

Comment: Per my question I am trying to avoid using a dictionary as it does not preserve the order of the list (at least in 2.6)

Comment: @Laughingwithu see mine

Comment: @mad physicist there would be no issue with that as it's still simple to access. I am playing with U9-Forward's answer as it works albiet I need to delete the duplicated lists (I need to read up about zip about more obviously as i did not realise you can create a tuple the way he/she has)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `zip` + `list comprehension` + product + for-loop + indexing (even works for below list):

```
from itertools import product
A = [["1a", "ab"], ["2b", "cd"], ["1a", "ef"], ['2b','gh']]
l,_=zip(*A)
l2=[idx for idx,i in enumerate(l) if l.count(i)>1]
l3=list(set([tuple(sorted((x,y))) for x,y in product(l2,repeat=2) if l[x]==l[y] and x!=y]))
for x,y in l3:
   A[x][1]=[A[x][1],A[y][1]]
   A.pop(y)
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[['1a', ['ab', 'ef']], ['2b', ['cd', 'gh']]]
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be it. I can't work out how to mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Laughingwithu Click the ✔ icon below my vote score buttons

Comment: @Laughingwithu Happy that i could help, 

Comment: @Laughingwithu Btw, when you have > 15 reputation you can upvote, if you want

Comment: @Laughingwithu I mean when you have more than 15 reputation

Comment: Been playing around with this but it only solves for the exact problem listed and doesn't work for bigger lists.

Comment: @Laughingwithu That's true, i did a mistake

Comment: @Laughingwithu Updated my answer